# NullReferenceException in Image Upload with C# web API and Reactjs

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, ienumerable, iformfile

I am trying to upload multiple images at once and saving the image names by comma-separated values in the Database. But there is an exception thrown right after I call the API endpoint for uploading the selected images. I am trying to save the image files in an **IEnumerable** object. And then traversing the object to get the names of the files. Is that the reason for the error? Thank you for any help.

**My ReactJS code snippet looks like this:**

```
const showPreview = e =>{
        console.log(e.target.files)
        var files = e.target.files;
        var formD = new FormData();

        formD.append('UId', userId);
        formD.append('UEmail', userEmail);
        formD.append('FComment', comment);
        formD.append('FImageFile', files );


        exampleAPI().create(formD)
        .then( res => {
            
            setComment(""); // AFTER THE COMMENT IS POSTED THE COMMENT GET CLEARED FROM THE COMMENT BOX
            document.getElementById('imageUploader').value = null; //THE CHOSEN IMAGE FILE NAME GET CLEARED AFTER COMMENT HAS BEEN POSTED
            setLoading(true);
        
        })
        .catch(err=> console.log(err))

    }

return(
         <div className="imageUploadDiv">
             <input type="file" accept='image/*' className='imageFile' onChange={showPreview} id="imageUploader" multiple/>
         </div>
)
```

My C# code looks like this. The issue happens here, it says **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
PEI_API.EF.PeiFeedback.FImageFile.get returned null.**
I have uploaded the error screenshot after the code as well.

```
[Route("PostComment")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostComment([FromForm] PeiFeedback comment)
        {

            foreach (var file in comment.FImageFile)
            {
                comment.FImageName += await SaveImage(file) + ",";
            }

            _db.PeiFeedbacks.Add(comment);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();

        }

[NonAction]
        public async Task<string> SaveImage(IFormFile imageFile)
        {
            string imageName = "";
            if (imageFile != null)
            {
                imageName = new String(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageFile.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(' ', '-');
                imageName = imageName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(imageFile.FileName);
                var imagePath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "images/comments", imageName);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    await imageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }

            return imageName;
        }
```

This is the error screenshot
[image: Error Screenshot]

**And this is the PeiFeedback class**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

#nullable disable

namespace PEI_API.EF
{
    public partial class PeiFeedback
    {
        public PeiFeedback()
        {
            PeiReplies = new HashSet<PeiReply>();
        }

        public int FId { get; set; }
        public int UId { get; set; }
        public string UEmail { get; set; }
        public string FComment { get; set; }
        public string FImageName { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<IFormFile> FImageFile { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string FImageSrc { get; set; } // not in data table
        public DateTime? FTimeStamp { get; set; }

        public virtual PeiUser U { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PeiReply> PeiReplies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are uploading a file blob and string without header : `Content-Type:multipart/form-data`,  that means no file data be send to server, that cause your `comment.FImageFile` is null (beacause you are not assign a empty list to that property)

Comment: how do I change it to work? It would be really helpful for me

Comment: @Sami you need to configure the request header in `exampleAPI().create(formD)`, and  for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options